# Transforming MariaDB sql to Posgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, mariadb

I have the following sql code for MariaDB and it is working, but now I try to rewrite it into to sql for PostgreSQL and get an error.

The sql code for MariaDb is:

```
SELECT monthname(f.datetime) AS month, 
sum(case when f.amount >= 0 then f.amount else 0 end) AS income, 
sum(case when f.amount < 0 then f.amount else 0 end) AS expense, 
sum(f.amount) as difference 
from finance.finance f
where f.country not in ("ZZ")
and year(f.datetime) = $year
GROUP BY monthname(f.datetime)
order by month(f.datetime)
```

and the code in sql in PostgreSQL is:

```
select to_char(f.datetime, 'Month') as month, 
sum(case when f.amount >= 0 then f.amount else 0 end) as income, 
sum(case when f.amount < 0 then f.amount else 0 end) as expense, 
sum(f.amount) as difference 
from finance f
where f.country not in ('ZZ')
and extract(year from f.datetime) = $year
GROUP BY to_char(f.datetime, 'Month')
order by to_char(f.datetime, 'MM')
```

But I get the following error:
ERROR: column "f.datetime" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

The following sql code works but gives the month as a number with a leading zero.

```
select to_char(f.datetime, 'MM') as month, 
sum(case when f.amount >= 0 then f.amount else 0 end) as income, 
sum(case when f.amount < 0 then f.amount else 0 end) as expense, 
sum(f.amount) as difference 
from finance f
where f.country not in ('ZZ')
and extract(year from f.datetime) = $year
GROUP BY to_char(f.datetime, 'MM')
order by to_char(f.datetime, 'MM')
```

How can I solve it? I want to have the first column as month name, thus no month numbers or timestamps.

Comment: in postgres 16 it works https://dbfiddle.uk/FWPZsAAa

Comment: @nbk pay attention to the 'ORDER BY'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply add the MM t6o the `GROUP BY` it wouldn't change the result and so you use it to `ORDER BY`

```
CREATE tABLE finance (datetime timestamp, amount int, country text)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
select to_char(f.datetime, 'Month') as month, 
sum(case when f.amount >= 0 then f.amount else 0 end) as income, 
sum(case when f.amount < 0 then f.amount else 0 end) as expense, 
sum(f.amount) as difference 
from finance f
where f.country not in ('ZZ')
and extract(year from f.datetime) = 2021
GROUP BY to_char(f.datetime, 'Month'), to_char(f.datetime, 'MM')
ORDER BY to_char(f.datetime, 'MM')
```

| month | income | expense | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pwNXgE29)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subselect:

```sql
select month_text, income, expense, difference from (
 select 
  to_char(f.datetime, 'Month') as month_text, 
  extract(month from f.datetime) as month_num,
  sum(case when f.amount >= 0 then f.amount else 0 end) as income, 
  sum(case when f.amount < 0 then f.amount else 0 end) as expense, 
  sum(f.amount) as difference 
 from finance f
 where f.country not in ('ZZ')
  and extract(year from f.datetime) = $year
 GROUP BY to_char(f.datetime, 'Month'), extract(month from f.datetime)
) t
order by month_num
```

Comment: that is unncessary